# How to submit UI ideas to Apple for consideration

Tags: ui

`Doubletap` (rapid-successive) of the iPhone's power button (aka "side" button) could be intepreted by the iPhone to invoke an app or action that is user-configured (camera, etc.).  Where is the appropriate forum to submit ideas as such ideas?

Comment: on iPhone 7 plus, with iOS 13 Beta you already can take pictures using that power button. Even inside apps like whatsapp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All suggestions or feedback should submitted to https://www.apple.com/feedback/.

Select "Feature Request" under "Feedback Type"
[image]